# How do jump-tables work?

Tags: c++, c, performance, latency

In the following document, pages 4-5:

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/ESC_Boston_01_304_paper.pdf

```
typedef int (* jumpfnct)(void * param); 
static int CaseError(void * param) 
{ 
  return -1; 
} 
static jumpfnct const jumptable[] = 
{ 
  CaseError, CaseError, ... 
  . 
  . 
  . 
  Case44,    CaseError, ... 
  . 
  . 
  . 
  CaseError, Case255 
}; 
  result = index <= 0xFF ? jumptable[index](param) : -1;
```

it is comparing IF-ELSE vs SWITCH and then introduces this "Jump table". Apparently it is the fastest implementation of the three. What exactly is it? I cannot see how it could work??

Comment: Could you clarify which part of it you don't understand? 

And as to whether it is "the fastest implementation" is probably largely depending on what happens in a switch - it is ALMOST certainly faster than an IF-ELSE chain of significant length, but a 256 way if-else could be done in 8 steps if you think about it a bit [and values are sequential, but that's assumed in this solution]

Comment: It is a topic discussed on SO a few times and I had written something about this for a similar thread a while ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12382959/switch-statement-with-huge-number-of-cases/12384086#12384086

Comment: It may also be worth bearing in mind that the paper cited does note that the compilers tested already generated jump-tables for typical switch statements. As always, profile first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The jumptable is a method of mapping some input integer to an action. It stems from the fact that you can use the input integer as the index of an array.

The code sets up an array of pointers to functions. Your input integer is then used to select on of these function-pointers. Generally, it looks like it's going to be a pointer to the function `CaseError`. However, every now and again, it will be a different function that is being pointed to.

It's designed so that

```
  jumptable[62] = Case62;
  jumptable[95] = Case95;
  jumptable[35] = Case35;
  jumptable[34] = CaseError; /* For example... and so it goes on */
```

Thus, selecting the right function to call is constant time... with the if-elses and selects, the time taken to select the correct function is dependent on the input integer... assuming the compiler doesn't optimize the select to a jumptable itself... if it's for embedded code, then there's a chance that optimizations of this kind have been disabled... you'd have to check.

Once the correct function-pointer is found, the last line simply calls it:

```
result = index <= 0xFF ? jumptable[index](param) : -1;
```

becomes

```
result = index <= 0xFF  /* Check that the index is within
                           the range of the jump table */

         ? jumptable[index](param) /* jumptable[index] selects a function
                                      then it gets called with (param) */

         : -1; /* If the index is out of range, set result to be -1
                  Personally, I think a better choice would be to call
                  CaseError(param) here */
```

Comment: so we trade the cost of a branch (expensive) for the cost of a stack pointer (to the function) (cheap-ish)

Comment: Essentially, although the relative cost of the two depends on your chipset. Also, for a sparse jumptable, there's probably a marginal cost in code-space... 256 * function pointer size, versus however many opcodes needed to implement your branching

Comment: @user997112 don't forget to accept any answers that you find useful... if you have any more questions about this answer, let me know and i'll improve it.

Comment: Sorry, its that annoying rule where you cant accept before 10 mins

Answer (score 2):

Jumpfnct is a pointer to a function.  Jumptable is an array that consists of a number of jumpfncts.  The functions can be called just by referencing their position in the array.

For example, jumptable0 will execute the first function, passing along param.  jumptable1 will execute the second function, etc.

If you don't know about function pointers, you shouldn't use this trick.  They're very handy, in a narrow domain.

It's very fast and space efficient, when what you're doing is switching between a large number of similar function calls.  You are adding a function call overhead that a switch statement doesn't necessarily have, so it might not be appropriate in all circumstances.  If your code is something like this:

```
switch(x) {
  case 1:
    function1();
    break;
  case 2:
    function2();
    break;
...
}
```

A jump table might be a good substitution.  If, though, your switch is something like this:

```
switch(x) {
  case 1:
    y++;
    break;
  case 1023:
    y--;
    break;
...
}
```

It probably wouldn't be worth doing.

I've used them in a toy FORTH language interpreter, where they were invaluable, but in most cases you're not going to see a speed benefit that makes them worth using.  Use them if it makes the logic of your program clearer, not for optimization.

Answer (score 2):

A Jump-Table is an obvious, but rarely used optimization, that for some reason seems to have fallen out of favor.

Briefly, instead of testing a value and exiting out of a switch/case or if-else block to branch to function or code path, you create an array which is filled with the addresses of the functions the program can branch to.

Once completed, this arrangement eliminates the relentless if testing attendant with if-else and switch/case blocks. The code uses the variable that would otherwise be tested with if as a subscript into the function-pointer array, and proceeds directly the the appropriate code - sans ANY if testing. A perfectly efficient branch. The assembly code should literally be a jump.

If you profile code, and find a hot-spot where the program is spending a large % of it's time, look to this kind of optimization to improve performance. A little bit of this can go a long way if it's part of a code's hot-spot.

Thanks for the link. Nice find!

Comment: I have to point out that, for example, a long chain of if/else will not necessarily show up as a hot-spot, because each if/else doesn't take very long. Also a switch statement may turn into a number of if/else like statement if the compiler decides that it's a better choice than a table of places to jump to.

Comment: I wouldn't look for if/else or switch/case blocks to CAUSE the hot-spot, but if they are participating in that stream of code, then the optimization is warranted.

Comment: Yes, my point is that when you have one function that uses maybe 10-15% of the total time, and it's "all over the place", it's hard to see what the problem is. (A similar problem is when you inline a function to 150 different places - it takes 12% of the total time, but because it's not in one place, you don't see it!)

Comment: Intel Vtune will find those fast.

Comment: Not in my experience, but being an AMD fanboy and using Linux, I guess it's more oprofile that I'm using these days. Used to use VTune a lot in the past, before they started checking the processor type before installing.

Answer (score 1):

This jumptable returns a pointer-to-function by its index. You define this table in a way that invalid indexes point to the function that returns some invalid code (like -1 in the example) and valid indexes point to the functions you need to call.

Construction

```
jumptable[index]
```

returns pointer-to-function and this function gets called

```
jumptable[index](param)
```

where `param` is some custom parameter.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment above, whether this solution is more or less effiicent than, for example, a switch statement depends on the amount of work needed to be done for each case.

Writing a regular switch statement for the values you want to process will definitely be a clearer way to see what the code does. So unless either space or speed requirements dictate that a more sophisticated solution, I would suggest that this is not a "better" solution.

Tables of function pointers is however an efficient and good way to solve certain problems. I use function pointers in a table quite regularly to do things like "Benchmark 11 different solutions to a problem", where I have a struct wiht the name of the function and the function, and some parameters perhaps. Then I have one function to time and loop over the code a few million times (or whatever it takes to get a long enough measurement to make sense)

Comment: I usually use a macro, like this:
`#define BENCH(func, param1, param2) { #func, func, param1, param2 }`
to fill in the table with the name, function pointer and parameters.

Comment: Very nice. This makes the playing field as level as possible for benchmarking. Thank you Mats.

Comment: Yes, indeed. Works as long as the thing you are measuring isn't very tiny - in which case you need macros that use timestamp counters or other "clock-cycle timers".